# Make td contents first select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, replace

Is there any way to find the text content of a td and then make that text the first line or option in a select drop down?

```
<table class="options">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Colour:</b></td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option selected="" value="">Select:</option>
                    <option value="1">Black</option>
                    <option value="2">White</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The first td content (Colour:) needs to go in place of the first option (Select:), basically. I don't have full control over the select list myself so I'm having to try doing this dynamically. Trying to save on space. Ideally I'd like to remove the td as well after moving the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the caption from the previous cell and put it to the first option. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/w07vg0ef/

Try this:

```
// do for all selects on the page
$('select').each(function (index, element) {

    // store the select
    var select = $(element)

    // get the caption from the previous cell
    var caption = select.parent().prev('td').text()

    // put the caption to the first option
    select.find('option').first().html(caption) 
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to remove the first td having taken its content?

Comment: Sure, just use: `var caption = select.parent().prev('td').text().remove()`

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. Would you mind updating the full code in case I've put that in the wrong place?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This works: `var caption = select.parent().prev('td').remove().text()`. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/w07vg0ef/2/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').prepend('<option selected=selected>'+$('select').closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text()+'</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="options">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Colour:</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option selected="" value="">Select:</option>
          <option value="1">Black</option>
          <option value="2">White</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

try this

Comment: Good answer, although what makes you think they are using JQuery?

Comment: @Feathercrown  I think it might be because it's tagged jquery.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do it only by `JavaScript` then take a look at this:

Add option as the first value but as a new value:

```js
var getColor = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
var selectedColor = getColor.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].innerHTML;
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = selectedColor;
select.add(option, select[0]);
```

```html
<table class="options">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b>Color:</b></td>
<td>
<select>
<option selected="" value="">Select:</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="2">White</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Add option as a replace value of the current first value:

```js
var getColor = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
var selectedColor = getColor.getElementsByTagName("b")[0].innerHTML;
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
var option = select.options[0];
option.innerHTML = selectedColor;
```

```html
<table class="options">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b>Color:</b></td>
<td>
<select>
<option selected="" value="">Select:</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="2">White</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick pure javascript solution.  If possible, I would add a class to the TD so you could target it better or something like that.

```js
var firstTD = document.getElementsByClassName('options')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
var text = firstTD.innerHTML;

var selectBox = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.setAttribute('value', '');
option.innerHTML = text;


selectBoxFirstChild = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].children[0];
selectBox.insertBefore(option, selectBoxFirstChild);
```